# Get Child classes from base class

Tags: c#, class

Is it possible in C# to get types of subclasses from base class?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Not directly, however you can use [AppDomain.GetAssemblies()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.getassemblies.aspx) to get all the currently loaded assemblies, and then use [Assembly.GetTypes()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.gettypes%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) to get all the types in that assembly. Then use [Type.IsSubclassOf()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.issubclassof.aspx) to determine if it's a subclass of the type you're after.

Comment: Is there a way to get only user assemblies (as opposed to system assemblies)? If there is an option to get this assembly and all referenced (to this) assemblies that would be a good solution.

Comment: Found it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getreferencedassemblies.aspx

Answer (score 40):

You can do this:

```
var subclassTypes = Assembly
   .GetAssembly(typeof(BaseClass))
   .GetTypes()
   .Where(t => t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(BaseClass)));
```

Answer (score 5):

you can select the Assembly you want to check, get the types with the method `Assembly.GetTypes()` and test for each of them if it is a subclass with `Type.IsSubclassOf()`

see [Assembly members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly_members.aspx) and [Type members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type_members.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

try this code:

```
public static IEnumerable<Type> GetAllSubclassOf(Type parent)
{
    foreach (var a in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
        foreach (var t in a.GetTypes())
            if (t.IsSubclassOf(parent)) yield return t;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see the following sample code, it is similar to other codes except it is not using lambda expressions and extension methods and tested with specific class in Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 console application.

Please also see its comments, output and screenshot for more detail.

**C#**

```
// Get all the types in your assembly. For testing purpose, I am using Aspose.3D, you can use any.
var allTypes = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Aspose.ThreeD.Formats.SaveOptions)).GetTypes();

foreach(var myType in allTypes)
{
    // Check if this type is subclass of your base class
    bool isSubType = myType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Aspose.ThreeD.Formats.SaveOptions));

    // If it is sub-type, then print its name in Debug window.
    if (isSubType)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(myType.Name);
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
AMFSaveOptions
ColladaSaveOptions
Discreet3DSSaveOptions
DracoSaveOptions
FBXSaveOptions
GLTFSaveOptions
HTML5SaveOptions
ObjSaveOptions
PdfSaveOptions
PlySaveOptions
RvmSaveOptions
STLSaveOptions
U3DSaveOptions
```

**Screenshot**
[image: Get sub-types from base-type with System.Reflection]

Comment: Since you're searching the assembly containing the baseclass, this will only work if all decendants are also defined in the same assembly.